# Does $p/q$ has at most $n-1$ zeros after a non zero number in its decimal expansion

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is the following true?

> Let $p$ and $q$ be integers and let $q$ be an integer with $n$ digits, then $p/q$ has at most $n-1$ zeros after a non zero number in its decimal expansion.

Comment: What about $1/2$ or $1/10$?

Comment: Perhaps he means the infinite decimal expansion without trailing zeroes, which is unique.

Comment: they are not a contradiction the 1/2 and 1/10.  two is a one digit number and 1/2 has decimal expansion  0.5 and therefore it has no zeroes after a non zero number as expected. and 1/10 has decimal expansion 0.1 so again no zeroes after a non zero number

Comment: So you would like only finite expansions?

Comment: any expansion that does not end with infinite zeroes for example I dont see 1/2 as 0.5000000000...... but just as 0.5

Comment: So more precisely: Between any two consecutive nonzero decimals there are at most $n-1$ consecutive zeroes?

Comment: I know this is true but is it an elementary fact? I couldn't find any theorem or lemma saying this?

Comment: yes I mean n-1 consequtive zeroes, sorry I was unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decimal expansion (where wlog. $p>0$) is computed as follows:

1. Perform division with remainder: $p=a\cdot q+b$ with $0\le b<q$. Write $a$ and a decimal point.
2. Let $p\leftarrow b$
3. *[Now $0\le p<q$].* Perform division with remainder: $10p=a\cdot q+b$ with $0\le b<q$.
4. *[Now $0\le a\le 9$].* Write $a$. If $b=0$, terminate; otherwise goto 2.

If step 4 outputs $k$ consecutive zeroes, then the value of $p$ gets multiplied by $10$ in each round. In the $k$th of these rounds $p$ is $10^{k-1}$ times the value it was in the first such round, and this must be $<q$ (and on the other hand nonzero). Hence $k$ zeroes mean that $q>10^{k-1}$.